# pandas read_hdf throwing a NoSuchNodeError

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Thanks in advance for your assistance.

I have a pandas dataframe which I have recently written to a hdf file using 'pandas.to_hdf(filename,key='mykey')'.

When I go to read that file back in using 'pandas.read_hdf(filename,key='mykey')' I get the following error. I have undertaken the same process with a number of other files containing the same type of data without issue. This one has just thrown an error for some reason. I can't seem to find any reference to a "NoSuchNodeError" associated with pandas, so your help is appreciated!

Thanks

```
NoSuchNodeError                           Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-44-8b1ddd34a084> in <module>
     27 
     28 
---> 29 data = pd.read_hdf(fname,key='mykey')
     30 
     31 print('Loaded data from file')

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\pytables.py in read_hdf(path_or_buf, key, mode, **kwargs)
    392                                      'contains multiple datasets.')
    393             key = candidate_only_group._v_pathname
--> 394         return store.select(key, auto_close=auto_close, **kwargs)
    395     except:
    396         # if there is an error, close the store

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\pytables.py in select(self, key, where, start, stop, columns, iterator, chunksize, auto_close, **kwargs)
    739                            chunksize=chunksize, auto_close=auto_close)
    740 
--> 741         return it.get_result()
    742 
    743     def select_as_coordinates(

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\pytables.py in get_result(self, coordinates)
   1481 
   1482         # directly return the result
-> 1483         results = self.func(self.start, self.stop, where)
   1484         self.close()
   1485         return results

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\pytables.py in func(_start, _stop, _where)
    732             return s.read(start=_start, stop=_stop,
    733                           where=_where,
--> 734                           columns=columns)
    735 
    736         # create the iterator

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\pytables.py in read(self, start, stop, **kwargs)
   2926 
   2927             _start, _stop = (start, stop) if i == select_axis else (None, None)
-> 2928             ax = self.read_index('axis%d' % i, start=_start, stop=_stop)
   2929             axes.append(ax)
   2930 

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\pytables.py in read_index(self, key, **kwargs)
   2521             return self.read_sparse_intindex(key, **kwargs)
   2522         elif variety == u('regular'):
-> 2523             _, index = self.read_index_node(getattr(self.group, key), **kwargs)
   2524             return index
   2525         else:  # pragma: no cover

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tables\group.py in __getattr__(self, name)
    838             self._g_add_children_names()
    839             return self.__dict__[name]
--> 840         return self._f_get_child(name)
    841 
    842     def __setattr__(self, name, value):

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tables\group.py in _f_get_child(self, childname)
    710         self._g_check_open()
    711 
--> 712         self._g_check_has_child(childname)
    713 
    714         childpath = join_path(self._v_pathname, childname)

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tables\group.py in _g_check_has_child(self, name)
    397             raise NoSuchNodeError(
    398                 "group ``%s`` does not have a child named ``%s``"
--> 399                 % (self._v_pathname, name))
    400         return node_type
    401 

NoSuchNodeError: group ``/mykey`` does not have a child named ``axis0``
```